# Spark, DataSource V2 API: How to partition data when writing to custom DataSource?

Tags: apache-spark

I created a Data source using the V2 API with write support. I now want to partition my data:

```scala
data.
  write.
  partitionBy("foo").
  format("my.format").
  save("...")
```

However, all the data is written "flat" to the output directory. I expected directories like `foo=bar`, `foo=moo` etc., as is the case when e.g. saving to CSV or Parquet.

When digging around the source code, it seems like the `partitioningColumns` field which is populated by `partitionBy` is only used when saving to an old V1 Data source.

Do I have to implement the partitioning myself and supply the partitioning columns elsewhere, e.g. via the options?